# Object.assign vs lodash _.assign

Tags: ecmascript-6, lodash

Looking at the documentation for [ES6 Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) 
and [Lodash _.assign](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) it looks like these function in exactly the same way.

Is that a correct understanding?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Certainly ,they're designed to do the same thing. The only difference I can see is that `Object.assign` converts primitive values to objects while `_.assign` does not (e.g., `Object.assign("hello", { foo: 1 })`)

Comment: The best way is to study [their](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/vendor/underscore/underscore.js#L1036-L1060) [sources](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill). However, in the case of lodash this is a bit complicated, as it does change from release to release - the [changelog](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Changelog) even mentions differences in behaviour.

Comment: thanks @apsillers!  that's a great distinction to know about.  if you feel like writing up an answer i'll upvote your response.

Comment: vs angular.copy(). I thought I'd throw this in for fun.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Depends on the browser. Per the lodash docs:

> Made _.assign use built-in Object.assign when available.

You can go here for browser support:

Basically, IE doesn't have support so lodash's code is used in that case

[MDN Docs on Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  I realize that some browsers do not yet have support for Object.assign.  I was wondering, for those environments to do offer both, is there a difference between the two?

Comment: lodash defers to the browser, so no, the native implementation is used in that case

Comment: ah! sorry! i misread your answer. I see now what you are saying (that lodash itself uses Object.assign when available, which makes it sound as if the lodash author didn't intend for there to be any distinction between the two).  very helpful.  thanks @JordanHendrix!

Comment: no problem! and yes, thats the case, for Object.assign

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the other comments, according to [this](https://measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/20797/0/lodashassign-vs-objectassign) small benchmark, it seems that Object.assign is a bit faster then Lodash.assign.