# Which is better to extend a Javascript Object with lodash? Whats the difference?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

Suppose you have a Javascript object and want to add some methods or properties to it, the way I came up with first was simply extending the prototype object of it, something like this.

```
someObject.prototype.someMethod = () => doSomething()
```

I think this is the way we all do back in the day.
But if you use lodash you can just do the same more elegantly and it looks easy to add more and more methods in it if you feel like it in the future.

```
_.assign(someObject, {
  someMethod: () => doSomething(),
})
```

I saw some codes and blogs do this but am wondering why not just do something like this?

```
_.assign(someObject.prototype, {
  someMethod: () => doSomething(),
})
```

And what exactly is the different between the two and which is better after all?

Comment: If you can edit your question to remove the request for opinions ("which is better"), it would be on-topic. However, you might also want to research Object.assign, which is essentially what lodash's assign uses: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37123425/215552

Comment: If the question is about extending prototype vs instance, why is it limited  to Lodash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding properties to an object's prototype property is pretty much useless unless that object happens to be a function that is going to be used as a constructor. If it's any object that is not also a function, `prototype` is just an ordinary property:

```
var obj = {};
try {
  obj.prototype.someProp = 5; // Throws error, obj.prototype is undefined
} catch ( e ) { 
  obj.prototype = {}; // Nothing special about this
  obj.prototype.someProp = 5; // or this
  obj.someProp === undefined; // true
}
```

Adding properties to the actual prototype of an object (not the prototype property) affects all objects with that same prototype:

```
var obj = {};
Object.getPrototypeOf( obj ).someProp = 5;
var obj2 = {};
obj2.someProp === 5; // true
```

That doesn't seem to be what you want.

[_.assign](https://lodash.com/docs#assign) and [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) extend the actual object:

```
var obj = {};
Object.assign( obj, { someProp: 5 } );
obj.someProp === 5; // true
```